# spring security custom login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, form-authentication

I'm trying to follow an example for Spring Security with custom login with some customization of my own. Not sure where I'm making the mistake, but I'm unable to figure out why the custom form login is not working.  The page is redirected to the protected resource without authentication.

The project uses spring-data-jpa to get the data to display in the view.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>spring-security2</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="domain.app"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

</beans>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" >
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/login" 
            username-parameter="custom_username" 
            password-parameter="custom_password"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/films/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class FilmController {

    @Autowired
    private FilmRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String  film(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("films", repository.findAll());
        return "film";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/films")
    public String  popularFilms(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("films", repository.findByCategory("Popular"));
        return "films";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <c:url value="/login" var="loginVar" />
    <form action="${loginVar}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Email address</label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="custom_username"
                placeholder="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input
                type="password" class="form-control" name="custom_password"
                placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <span class="label label-danger">Invalid username or password</span>
        </c:if>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think spring is not able to recognize the filters place the delegating proxy filter below the all the configuration please tell me if it works

Comment: try adding the csrf protection tokens i dont see a token and you have also not disabled it

Comment: I too suspected that and added the csrf token but that too didn't work.  There is another application that is working and the only difference that I see is that it has root application context above security context and the context listener loader is above the the servlet definition in the web.xml.  I'll check that is causing any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `RequestMapping` with to handle `POST` to `/login` but you have specified it has the `login-processing-url`.

And furthermore try changing

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER"/>
```

to

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, and I allways found suspicious the fact of using the same mapping both for login page and login processing url. I have not seen any other issue in your config, so I would start trying to change one of those mappings, for example this way:

```
<security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/performLogin"
...
```

If you try this way, remember to change the login form action to point to the new `login-processing-url` endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

You have defined

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
```

but login form submit is POST call. So as per logic you have'nt defined any call to handle POST /login

Comment: GET and POST both required

Comment: But for POST call there is no RequestMapper

Comment: the post call will be handled by spring security implicitly you dont require a handler for that